# Add a dynamic function to an element using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to attach a dynamic `.change()` function to a list of elements:

```
els = new Array('#element1','#element2');

for (i=1; i < 3; i++){
    $(els[i]).change(function(){
        alert(i);
    });
}
```

This does not work as desired because `i` is not passed into the function, but is instead always equal to the last iteration, ie, 2. How do I pass a value into the `change(function{})`?

Comment: Have a look at http://blog.morrisjohns.com/javascript_closures_for_dummies.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways of doing this.

> Use `$.each`

```
var element_array = new Array('#element1','#element2');

$.each( element_array, function( index, value ){ 
    $(value).change(function(){ 
        alert( index ); 
    }); 
});
```

> Create a closure.

```
var element_array = new Array('#element1','#element2');

for ( i = 0; i < element_array.length; i++){
    (function(i){
        $(element_array[i]).change(function(){
            alert(i);
        });
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: Looking at this answers, there's some good info. I like the eventData solution from RamenRecon but for some reason I prefer the .each() method. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

All of your generated functions refer to the same variable: `i`. This variable subsequently changes when the loop continues, so that by the time your change event fires, `i` will be set to `2`.

You have to create a local scope that stores the value of `i` at the moment your function is being created:

```
els = new Array('#element1','#element2');

for (i=1; i < 3; i++){
    (function(i){
        $(els[i]).change(function(){
            alert(i);
        });
    })(i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery events can take eventData in the signiture and pass it as arguments to your callback function. From jQuery docs:

```
.change( [eventData], handler(eventObject) )
```

What you want is this (I've changed the arg name to keep it obvious):

```
for (i=1; i < 3; i++){
    $(els[i]).change({index: i}, function(event){
        alert(event.data.index);
    });
}
```

Comment: I think it has to be `alert(event.data.index);`.

Comment: Thanks, Felix.  Forgot about that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like that:

els = new Array('#element1','#element2');

`for (i=1; i < 3; i++){`
`$(els[i]).bind( 'change', function(){`
`alert(i);`
`});`
`}`

When you load the page, jQuery does not know the array's values and it is like a string.

Comment: .change is a shortcut for .bind( 'change',... They are essentially the same, that's not the problem.